# speeding vector push_back

Tags: c++, stdvector, push-back

I am trying to speed vector::push_back when capacity cant be predicted

When reserve is available a vector push_back writes the new element at the end of the container, and then the end marker is moved. After all reserve is used, push_back may trigger reallocation which is a slow process.
  To speed this up, reserve is regenerated for several coming push_back without reallocation when empty. How do you think this code assist in achieving that goal ?

```
#ifndef __VECTOR_HPP
#define __VECTOR_HPP
#include <exception>
#include "Concept.hpp" //Concept::RESA constant
#include <vector>
template <typename T>
class Vector : public std::vector<T> {
public :
  void push_back (T t) {
    if (std::vector<T>::size () == std::vector<T>::capacity ()) {
      std::vector<T>::reserve ((size_t) Concept::RESA);
    }
    std::vector<T>::push_back (t);
  }
};
#endif
```

Test program :

```
#include "Vector.hpp"

int main (int argc, char* argv []) {
  {
    std::vector<size_t> v0;
    clock_t t (clock ());
    size_t duration (0);
    for (size_t i (0); i != 10000000; i++) {
      v0.push_back (i);
    }
    duration = (size_t) (clock () -t);
    std::cout << "duration old push_back == " << duration << " ticks" << std::endl;
  }
  {
    size_t duration (0);
    Vector<size_t> v1;
    clock_t t (clock ());
    for (size_t i (0); i != 10000000; i++) {
      v1.push_back (i);
    }
    duration = (size_t) (clock () -t    );
    std::cout << "duration new push_back == " << duration << " ticks" << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Results :

with a Concept::RESA == 8192, and applying suggestions, here are the results on a Lenovo ThinkCentre icore5 (Linux Debian, g++) :

duration old push_back == 105317 ticks

duration new push_back == 87156 ticks

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve with this code?

Comment: What is the problem statement?

Comment: As explained in title : speeding push_back to a vector after all reserve is used

Comment: I'll ask in a slightly different way: How do *you* think this code does, or perhaps does *not*, assist in achieving that goal ? Frankly I don't see how this is any better, and in-fact is likely worse, than simply putting in a `val_.reserve(val_.capacity() + Concept::RESA)` if you know size == capacity prior to an insert.

Comment: @WhozCraig calling reserve directly with constant increments would make insertion O(n^2). By doing insert he still gets exponential growth because it is handled by std::vector. But that does not change the fact that this code is more than pointless and does something else than he thinks it does.

Comment: I tried to fix the question, but rolled back when I realized the poor wording is matched by the poor understanding of `std::vector`. Fixing the question makes it pointless. In particular, while the second sentence talks about "reserve is available", this does _not_ mean `vector::reserve`. It probably means `vector::capacity() greater than vector::size()`.

Comment: Can you explain a little more about what `val_.insert (val_.end (), resa_.begin (), resa_.end ());` is really supposed to be achieving? I'm having trouble understanding how it helps you be more efficient.

Comment: @AndyG coupled with `erase` it's used as a poor man's `reserve` here :)

Comment: @Ap31: I think I see what you mean. I suppose the resulting comment for the OP is that the resulting reallocation for vector will not be the distance between `resa_.begin()` and `resa_.end()`, but whatever the `vector`'s reallocation strategy is (likely a simple doubling of the underlying buffer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed `push_back` **may** trigger reallocation, which is a slow process.
It will not do so on every single `push_back` though, instead it will reserve exponentially more memory each time, so explicit `reserve` only makes sense if you have a good approximation of resulting vector size beforehand.

In other words, `std::vector` already takes care of what you are suggesting in your code.

Another point: [there is a `reserve` method](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) that serves the purpose much better than inserting and erasing elements, most notably it does not create and destroy actual objects.

Ironically as @Sopel mentioned replacing insert/erase with `reserve` in your class would disable vector's growth amortization, making your code a nice example of several mistakes (somewhat) cancelling each other.

Comment: If the vector already "takes care of what my code suggest", how do you explain the speed improved by 30%  ?

Comment: @Saint-Martin perhaps by lack of proper measuring - you didn't mention your OS, compiler, compiler flags, it's not clear what your `clock()` does, there's no warmup, the measurements are sequential => asymmetric etc.

Comment: Also my measurements (same source, MSVC14 -O2) show no difference

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues with your code.

- You're essentially defining a type very similar to `std::vector` with `std::vector` as its only member. Why not using a `std::vector` in the first place?
- Your `push_back()` function is just terrible. Let me first explain what `std::vector<>::push_back()` actually does.

  1. if `size()<capacity()`: it just copies the new element at the end of the block and increments the `end` marker. **This is the most common situation**.
  2. **only** if `size()==capacity()`, re-allocation is needed and

     1. it allocates a new block of memory, typically twice the current capacity
     2. it moves all data to the begin of the new block
     3. it de-allocates the old block of memory
     4. it finally constructs a new element at the end of the data

  Let's now see what your

  ```
  void push_back (const T& t) {
    if (val_.size () == val_.capacity ()) {
      val_.insert (val_.end (), resa_.begin (), resa_.end ());
      auto i = val_.end();
      i -= (size_t) Concept::RESA;
      val_.erase (i, val_.end ());
    }
    val_.push_back (t);
  }
  ```

  does if `val_.size()==val_.capacity()`:

  1. it `insert()`s default-constructed element at `val_.end()`. To this end, `std::vector::insert()` does the following:

     1. it allocates a new block of memory, sufficiently large to hold the old data plus the data to be inserted, but possibly larger.
     2. it moves all data to the begin of the new block
     3. it de-allocates the old block of memory
     4. it copies the elements to be inserted at the end of the old data
  2. it the destructs all the newly inserted elements.
  3. if finally constructs a new element at the end of the data (which needs no re-allocation).

  Thus, your function too requires re-allocation *about as frequent as plain `std::push_back()`* and completely **unnecessarily** copy-constructs and then destroys a whole chunk of elements. There is **no way of avoiding re-allocation** when you want contiguous memory layout (as promised by `std::vector`) *and* don't know the final size in advance. If either of these requirements can be dropped, you can avoid re-allocation: either by `std::vector<>::reserve()` or by using a container with non-contiguous memory, such as [`std::deque`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque).

Comment: My Vector dont avoid reallocations : its just grouping them. A vector is faster than a deque.

Comment: @Saint-Martin: Can you elaborate on what you mean about how your vector is grouping its reallocations?

Comment: @Saint-Martin *A vector is faster than a deque* depends for what! If you have lots of `push_back()`, `insert()`, or even `push_front()`, `std::deque` is faster ...

Comment: @Saint-Martin Your code does the re-allocation about as often as plain `std::vector<>::push_back()`. In particular, there no *grouping* and no benefit.

Comment: check test result. Not so sure deque is the fastest for push_back (a vector having a reserve should be faster). Is it necessary to redo the test and compare Vector to deque ?